# Remove files with certain extensions and 0-length files

Tags: bash, shell-script, files

Want to know how we can clean the directory by removing all the files with a zero length , with a .tmp or with a .swp extension that found in this directory (note that sometimes .swp and .tmp files are hidden) in Bash Script.

Comment: What have you tried? You are supposed to make *some* effort with your homework...

Comment: i tried rm -r to remove all the files but its not on hidden files and i also tried  "" shopt -s dotglob  
rm -rf script/*  ""  but when i run this in my command ,this remove my whole ubuntu files and i reinstall my ubuntu .

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 files - checking their sizes.

```
 find . -type f \( -name "*.tmp" -o -name "*.swp" \) -ls
17717019        0 -rw-r--r--    1 jai              wheel                   0 Mar 23 09:10 ./a/.tmp
17717018        0 -rw-r--r--    1 jai              wheel                   0 Mar 23 09:10 ./a/x.swp
17717007        8 -rw-r--r--    1 jai              wheel                  38 Mar 23 09:09 ./b/y.swp
```

finding files with size 0 bytes -

```
$ find . -type f \( -name "*.tmp" -o -name "*.swp" \) -size 0c 
  ./a/.tmp
  ./a/x.swp
```

Deleting files with 0 size only --

```
 $ find . -type f \( -name "*.tmp" -o -name "*.swp" \) -size 0c -exec rm -i {} \;
    remove ./a/.tmp? y
    remove ./a/x.swp? y
    $
```

checking again -- only the non zero size file remains

```
$ find . -type f \( -name "*.tmp" -o -name "*.swp" \) -ls
    17717007        8 -rw-r--r--    1 jai              wheel                  38 Mar 23 09:09 ./b/y.swp
```